# Django - Can't remove empty_label from TypedChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have field in my model:

```
TYPES_CHOICES = (
    (0, _(u'Worker')),
    (1, _(u'Owner')),
)
worker_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, choices=TYPES_CHOICES)
```

When I use it in ModelForm it has "---------" empty value. It's TypedChoiceField so it hasn't empty_label attribute., so I can't override it in form **init** method.

Is there any way to remove that "---------"?

That method doesn't work too:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobOpinionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields['worker_type'].choices[0][0] == '':
            del self.fields['worker_type'].choices[0]
```

EDIT:

I managed to make it work in that way:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JobOpinionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.fields['worker_type'].choices[0][0] == '':
        worker_choices = self.fields['worker_type'].choices
        del worker_choices[0]
        self.fields['worker_type'].choices = worker_choices
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty option for any model field with choices determined within the `.formfield()` method of the model field class.  If you look at the django source code for this method, the line looks like this:

```
include_blank = self.blank or not (self.has_default() or 'initial' in kwargs)
```

So, the cleanest way to avoid the empty option is to set a default on your model's field:

```
worker_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, choices=TYPES_CHOICES, 
                                               default=TYPES_CHOICES[0][0])
```

Otherwise, you're left with manually hacking the `.choices` attribute of the form field in the form's `__init__` method.

Answer (score 4):

`self.fields['xxx'].empty_value = None` would not work If you field type is `TypedChoiceField` which do not have `empty_label` property.
What should we do is to remove first choice:

```
class JobOpinionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobOpinionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field and isinstance(field , forms.TypedChoiceField):
                field.choices = field.choices[1:]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JobOpinionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['worker_type'].empty_value = None
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield

Comment: It doesn't work. I edited my post and pasted working solution. Don't know if it's the best.

Comment: I have no idea. When I print it, I get empty data, but on site it shows "-------". Setting it to something else like: self.fields['worker_type'].empty_value = 'nothing' also doesn't work :)

Comment: `TypedChoiceField` do not have `empty_label`