# How to change empty_label for modelForm choice field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, dropdownbox

I have a field in one of my models like the following:

```py
PAYROLL_CHOICES = (
    ('C1', 'Choice1'),
    ('C2', 'Choice2')
    etc.....
)

payrollProvider = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PAYROLL_CHOICES)
```

When I create a model form for this field, Django correctly generates an HTML select box, but includes a default blank value of "---------".

I would like to know how to change this default value to some other text, such as "please choose value".

I believe I should be able to set this in my model form's **init** via the following, as documented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739260/customize-remove-django-select-box-blank-option) and several others:

```
self.fields['payrollProvider'].empty_label = "please choose value"
```

However, this isn't working for me. When I include that line in my form's **init**, "--------" still shows up as the initial choice in the select box. I'm pasting the relevant forms.py below, but it seems that others have [also been unable to access / modify empty_label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928565/django-cant-remove-empty-label-from-typedchoicefield). At this link, the questioner describes a way to *delete* the default empty_label value (which I was able to do successfully via his method) but what I really want to do is to *modify* the empty_label that is displayed.

Any ideas?

Here's the code for the form in forms.py, with the empty_label code that isn't successful at changing the default "----------":

```
class PayrollCredentialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PayrollCredentialForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['payrollUsername'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'yp-signup'})
        self.fields['payrollPassword'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'yp-signup'})
        self.fields['payrollProvider'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'yp-signup'})
        self.fields['payrollUsername'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder' : '  Payroll Username'})
        self.fields['payrollPassword'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder' : '  Payroll Password'})
        self.fields['payrollProvider'].empty_label = "please choose value"


class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = ('payrollProvider', 'payrollUsername', 'payrollPassword')
    widgets = {
        'payrollPassword': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to specify something that is not available for the type of Select field.

The empty_label option is for forms.ModelChoiceField, which happens to use a Select widget, but is not the same kind of field as your CharField that you are providing options for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

You can see this also in a previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/740011/1406860

You could try and override the html of the modelform to add the first option as "please choose value". Alternatively, you could use a template filter to do the same thing. Lastly, you could and ("", "please choose value") to PAYROLL_CHOICES, and if you don't want it to be submitted without a payrollProvider just set blank=False for the field in the model.

JD

Answer (score 16):

dokkaebi, that won't work properly. You'll receive the following *select* code:

```
<select name="payrollProvider" id="id_payrollProvider">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="" selected="selected">please choose value</option>
<option value="C1">Choice1</option>
<option value="C2">Choice2</option>
</select>
```

The only relatively convenient way that came to my mind is to do something like this in the form:

```
class PayrollCredentialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PayrollCredentialForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["payrollProvider"].choices = [("", "please choose value"),] + list(self.fields["payrollProvider"].choices)[1:]
```

Comment: A lifesaver after 3 hours of banging my head against a wall. Changing the blank label looks to be possible in 1.7.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, now (as of **Django** `1.8` and higher) override of an `empty_label` works:

```
class PayrollCredentialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PayrollCredentialForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['payrollProvider'].empty_label = 'Please, choose value'
```

Also, if you working with **Django Admin**, there is an option to set empty value for a list view:

```
class PayrollCredentialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('payrollProvider_value', )

    def payrollProvider_value(self, instance):
        return instance.payrollProvider
    payrollProvider_value.empty_value_display = 'Empty value'
```

---

**What if field should be `readonly`?**

There is a catch if field modified in such way should be `readonly`.

If overridden form field will be specified in `readonly_fields` attribute inside `PayrollCredentialAdmin` class, it would result in `KeyError` exception in `PayrollCredentialForm` (because `readonly` field won't be included in form's `self.fields`). To handle that, it's required to override `formfield_for_dbfield` instead of using `readonly_fields`:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    field = super(PayrollCredentialAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(
        db_field, **kwargs
    )
    db_fieldname = canonical_fieldname(db_field)

    if db_fieldname == 'payrollProvider':
        field.widget = forms.Select(attrs={
            'readonly': True, 'disabled': 'disabled',
        })

    return field
```

Might be useful.

---

Update for **Django** `1.11`:

Comments below brought assumption that such override is no longer valid for newer version of Django.

Comment: Strange, it worked for me on Django 1.9 (not tested specifically 1.9.7 though). Upvotes confirmed that this is a working solution. Maybe you've made a mistake somewhere in the code?

Comment: Can you Post the whole Form (including the field you used) for comparsion? I solved it over adding an empty choice buts it kind of annoying since ModelChoice has that option (and it works)

Comment: confirmed this doesn't work for me either (in django 1.11) I had to use pythonpro's answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your forms.py file,
This would definitely work.. Try this...

```
     class Meta:
        model = StaffDetails
        fields =['photo','email', 'first_name','school','department', 'middle_name','last_name','gender', 'is_active']
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StaffDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Field_name'].empty_label = 'Please Select'
```

It worked for me.. just replace the field names with yours...

Answer (score 1):

Only `ModelChoiceField` (generated for `ForeignKey` fields) supports the `empty_label` parameter, and in that case it's tricky to get at as those fields are usually generated by `django.forms.models.ModelFormMetaclass` within a call to `django.forms.models.modelform_factory`.

`ModelFormMetaclass` uses the `empty_label` param to add another choice to the list, with `empty_label` as the display and `''` as its value.

The simplest way to do what you want is just to add an empty choice to your choices list:

```
PAYROLL_CHOICES = (
        ('', 'please choose value'),
        ('C1', 'Choice1'),
        ('C2', 'Choice2'),

        etc.....
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way worked for me is:

```
country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.filter(), empty_label='--Select--')
```

However, my Django version is 2.2.7

Answer (score 1):

Just add a tuple to your `model.field.choices` with a value of **None**:

```
 payrollProvider = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PAYROLL_CHOICES)
 PAYROLL_CHOICES = (
        (None, 'please choose'),
        ('C1', 'Choice1'),
        ('C2', 'Choice2')
        etc.....
                    )
```

From the [docs (v4.0)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices):

> Unless blank=False is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. **To override this behavior, add a tuple to choices containing None**; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display'). Alternatively, you can use an empty string instead of None where this makes sense - such as on a CharField.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [Javed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984013/how-to-change-empty-label-for-modelform-choice-field/68664171#answer-44195598) answer. Since I have tons of fields in my form I just want to replace all labels in the html by placeholders so for select tags I use their field label.

```
class PacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Paciente
        fields=('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PacienteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for f in self.fields:
            if hasattr(self.fields[f], 'choices'):
                choices=self.fields[f].choices
                if type(choices) == list:
                    choices[0]=('',self.fields[f].label)
                    self.fields[f].choices=choices
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **Empty String** with **"Please Select"** to choices as shown below:

```py
class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        class Months(models.TextChoices):
            EMPTY_LABEL = '', 'Please Select' # Here
            JANUARY = 'JAN', 'January'
            FEBRUARY = 'FEB', 'February'
            MARCH = 'MAR', 'March'
                                 
        self.fields['month'].choices = Months.choices
```