# Set default text in dropdown for TypedMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django

The question pretty much says it all. I'm trying to change the default 'Select Options' text on a TypedMultipleChoiceField in my form. I've tried empty_value, widget title and looked through the Django docs but no luck. I'm not trying to set an initial value because the form is rendered through a formset so most of the time there are already selected options. Also, choices are set at runtime because the choice is dependent upon a fk. Any help would be awesome as I've spent more time than I'd like to admit trying to figure this out.

Comment: Did you try `empty_label` attribute? Oh, looks like it's only on `ModelChoiceField`, not sure if it would work here.

Comment: @RohitJain Sadly, Django doesn't allow empty_label on a TypedMultipleChoiceField for some reason.

Comment: Can you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14032358/1679863

Comment: @RohitJain I don't believe that actually changes what is at top so the only way to display it is to set it as the init value which would mess with the way I clean the form data if someone doesn't uncheck it.

Comment: It does.. If you see closely, the second part is getting the list starting from index 1 - `[1:]`?